# While iterating a dataframe, how can I place a newly found value into a new column at the same index?

Tags: pandas

```
for artist in test_data[:10]['artist']:    
    spotify_query = sp.search(artist, limit=1, type='artist')
    artist_id = spotify_query['artists']['items'][0]['id']
```

artist_id is returning a value I'd like to place in the same index of the DF I am iterating in a new column.

What is the preferred way to handle this in pandas? Some searching has led to me thinking using .index with df.at might work?

Comment: If you could please post a sample of the Pandas DataFrame that would make the question a bit clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was curious, Jonathan's reply led to me doing a lot of reading on dataframe iteration flavors. As someone still learning pandas iterations can be confusing at times, especially while building a functions using other libraries.

The function below assigns the 'spotify_query' result to the current index of the column being iterated.

```
def get_artist_id(x):
auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID') , client_secret=os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET') )
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager) 
spotify_query = sp.search(x, limit=1, type='artist')
try:
    artist_id = spotify_query['artists']['items'][0]['id']
except IndexError:
    artist_id = 'null'
return artist_id
```

Combined with apply this produces the expected result.

```
test_test['artist_id'] = test_test['artist'].apply(get_artist_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get the id, you can use iterrows() to add the artist_id. Here's a simplified version, but should get you started. Depending on the size of you dataframe, .apply() or .transform() or .agg() may be worth looking into.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'artist':['a', 'b', 'c']})
df['artist_id'] = ''
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # print(i, row['artist'])
    artist_id = random.randint(3, 90)
    print(artist_id)
    df.iloc[i]['artist_id'] = artist_id
```

Output:

```
39
75
64

In [75]: df
Out[75]:
  artist artist_id
0      a        39
1      b        75
2      c        64
```

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, I worked around with iterrows for a bit but eventually went with an apply method.